# using slidetoggle to expand dynamic div - how do I close the other when expanding this div?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am working on showing some dynamic content on a page. I am using the onclick function on the div that I want to expand and close. I have made it work such that I am able to open and close a div by clicking on it, but clicking on other div will not close the currently expanded one. I hope this makes sense. Some code:

```
<div class="container collapsed">
    <div id="a_<?php echo $a->id?>" class="<?php echo $div_class?>" onclick="$(this).find('.content').slideToggle();$(this).siblings().slideUp();">    
        <div class="t">
            <?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($a->start))?> - <?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($a->end))?>
        </div>
        <div class="i">
        <?php echo $a->id?>
        </div>
        <div class="tt">
            <?php echo $a->name?>
        </div>
        <div class="l">
            &nbsp;<?php echo $a->l?>
        </div>
    <?php while($c=$obj->fetchNextObject($sql)):?>
        <div class="c">
            <?php echo $c->name_2?>
        </div>
     <?php endwhile ?>
    <div class="content">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
            <div class="<?php echo $s_class?>">
    <div class="bottom_line"></div>
    <div class="bottom_line2"></div>  
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

I hope the code is not too obscurred. The problem really is the jQuery part - everything else works as it should. How do I make one div close when clicking on another div?

Comment: Which divs do you want to slide up and down?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you have multiple `<div class="container collapsed">`?

Comment: yes, there are multiple of these divs. they are dynamically created from a datadabe that takes in feeds. The problem occures when closing container collapsed #1 is opened and I then click e.g. container collapsed#2 which should close all other open/expanded divs. The only thing that closes a div is clicking on the same div again - which is fine, but the other thing should also work.

Comment: You should start with getting rid of the inline javascript, putting everything in one event handler where you will be able to handle all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself using the following onclick code on the first div (container_collapsed)

```
onclick="$(this).siblings().children().children('.content').slideUp(200);$(this).children().children('.content').slideToggle(200);"
```

Thanks for the input and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, separate your javascript. Anyway, I'll TRY to answer your question thought the code sample might not fit perfectly:
If I were to do this I'd use your class `collapsed`. For example:

```
$(function() {//on document load
    $('.container').click(function(){
        //close all containers
        $('.container:not(.collapsed)').slideUp();
        $('.container:not(.collapsed)').addClass('collapsed');
        //your code here to open the container clicked.
    });
});
```

This should collapse all containers that aren't already collapsed (or just collapse all of them regardless, should do the same thing.